# List row height at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

What's the right way to determine at execution time the **height** of the first **cell** of a **ListView**? The list is fullfilled with the result of an HTTP request and the list row layout has "**wrap_content**" for height. I need that height to set it to another view.

Comment: share sceen shot of your row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cell.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
             MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
```

This way is working, anyone can please explain me why? :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the height in the adapter when it generates the view for position 0

Comment: I've tried int height = adapter.getView(0, null, getListView()).getHeight(); but height is always 0.

Comment: Try getMeasuredHeight

Comment: Sorry, no luck with that, always 0.

Comment: Ok another try :) Force the view to measure with itemView.measure(UNSPECIFIED, UNSPECIFIED) and after that read the the height/measuredHeight again

Comment: The value is still 0. :(

Comment: damnn, what happen here :/ Can you give me a copy of your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to note WHEN you are doing the measurement.
You need to do this AFTER the layout has been calculated. You can try something like this in your onCreate:

```
 // add global layout listener on root view of your fragment
 rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
     @Override
     public void onGlobalLayout() {
        yourcell.measure()... // DO the measurement here...
     }
 }
```